# why there is extra comment tag in the final DOM generate by angualr

Tags: html, angular, typescript

bindings={
“ng-reflect-ng-if”: “false”
}

```
            <ng-template class=“no-result-product” [ngIf]=“products” [ngIfElse]=“noproducts”>
                <div class=“list-product” fxLayout=“row wrap” fxLayoutAlign=“center stretch” *ngIf=“products”>
                    <app-template-product *ngFor=“let product of products”
                                          class=“list-product__item”
                                          [product]=“product”>
                    </app-template-product>
                  </div>
               </ng-template>
               <ng-template #noproducts>
                <div> <img src=“./assets/img/shop/not-found-product.svg” alt=“”>
                  <div >{{ ‘not.found.product.message’ | translate }}</div>
                </div>
               </ng-template>
```

{{ ‘not.found.product.message’ | translate }} 
the content is not displayed !!

Comment: Please add some more code to help people understand what is going on. The extra "comment" that angular adds is showing you that the `ngIf` you're using to display DOM content is evaluating to false. That's all I can tell you without seeing your .ts code.

Answer (score 0):

here you are using `ngIf` directive, and passing your 2nd template inside of `ngIfElse` property

```
   <ng-template class=“no-result-product” [ngIf]=“products” [ngIfElse]=“noproducts”>
```

that means that your "else template" will appear if `products` value is falsy.